# how to add list and append item in json file

Tags: arrays, json

"how to append list and add entry in json file?"

i'm doing web scraping and trying to append a list in json file but i'm not able to understand logic.

[{"cloth": {"brand_name": "Amina", "designer": "Designs By Amina", "title": "Gota on Pure Chiffon"}},
{"cloth": {"brand_name": "Designs By Amina", "designer": "Designs By Amina", "title": "Designs By Amina"}}]

i want to create this type of file in json

Answer (score 1):

```
clothes_list=[]
for i in raw_data['cloth']:
   clothes_list.append(i)
```

This will return a list and then the list can easily convert into data frame.

```
clothes=pd.DataFrame(clothes_list)
```

you can describe it.

```
clothes.describe(include="all")
```